# How to manage permissions for a volume mounted into a docker container?

Tags: apache, docker, permissions, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm developing a Wordpress theme, and want to use Docker in my dev setup. What I've done is pretty simple:

- create a `database` service running MySQL 5.7
- create a `wordpress` service, where I mount my theme folder as a volume into `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes`

I'm struggling with the volume permissions, however.

I'm working with the following project folder structure:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── my-theme
```

My **`docker-compose.yml`** file looks like this:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - my_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - database
    image: wordpress:php7.3-apache
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: ./my-theme
        target: /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme
volumes:
  my_data: {}
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, everything works as expected: containers are created, and I can access Wordpress in the browser. However, the theme I mounted as a volume doesn't render anything when I activate it.

When I `sh` into the `wordpress` container (`docker-compose exec wordpress sh`) I can see that the `wp-content/themes` folder is owned by `root`. So I figured that was the problem.

I verified this being a permissions issue by manually and recursively `chown`ing the `wp-content` folder in the container:

```sh
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content
```

Once that was done, my theme rendered as expected. So now I'm looking for a way to avoid this `chown` process (the idea is that any other dev can clone this project, simply run `docker-compose up` and start working).

The first thing I tried was to make a **Dockerfile** where I would build a slightly customized Wordpress image:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.3-apache
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/test-theme \
  && chown -R /var/www/html/wp-content
```

My reasoning behind this was that by creating the directory and `chown`ing it beforehand, the volume would inherit the user:group mapping. Alas, no such thing; mounting the volume overrides this mapping and sets it back to `root:root`.

After that, I tried to set the `APACHE_RUN_USER` and `APACHE_RUN_GROUP` environment variables in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  database:
    ...

  wordpress:
    ...
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: database:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: root
      APACHE_RUN_USER: '$(id -u)'
      APACHE_RUN_GROUP: '$(id -g)'
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: ./my-theme
        target: /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme
volumes:
  my_data: {}
```

However, this threw a bunch of apache errors on build.

I'm at a bit of a loss here now. Is there any best practice for managing permissions of mounted volumes in Docker? I've googled a lot for this, but the solutions I do find go a little bit over my head.

Comment: What exactly are the Apache errors you face? I suspect `'$(id -u)'` to be wrong, as Shell variables are not evaluated between single quotes, although I'm not sure this applies here. Other than that, doing `chown` in your Dockerfile is totally legit ([here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259) is a GitHub issue discussing this problem.)

Comment: Indeed, I also thought that doing `chown` in Dockerfile would do the trick (based on same GH issue you linked), but it seems that once I mount a volume, the permissions are overridden and set back to root:root. I tested by doing `docker-compose up` with and without `volumes` key in wordpress service. When I sh into the container without mounted volume, `ls -l` shows `www-data:www-data` for wp-content folder. Once I mount the volume, `ls -l` shows `root:root`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this by overwriting the entrypoint for the wordpress image.

Create a file startup.sh in your project and make is executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wp-content
docker-entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground
```

Then in your docker-compose.yml:

```
...
  wordpress:
...
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
        - './my-theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my-theme'
        - './startup.sh:/startup.sh'
    entrypoint: /startup.sh
```

This worked for me, let me know if you have problems implementing it.

Comment: Hold on, I spoke too soon. The wordpress container build was just delayed more than usual but eventually came through. It's working now! Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Asked ChatGPT about the problem and got a solution:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

# Create a www-data user with the same UID and GID as the host user
ARG WWW_DATA_UID=1000
ARG WWW_DATA_GID=1000
RUN usermod -u $WWW_DATA_UID www-data && groupmod -g $WWW_DATA_GID www-data

# Rest of the Dockerfile...
```

By setting the UID and GID of the www-data user inside the container to the same values as the host machine, the ownership of the mounted files and directories should now correctly reflect the www-data user.

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
    wordpress:
        build:
            context: .
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html:rw
        user: www-data
```